# Select all rows where a row does not have a value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm tying to do a really simple query, however it keeps returning a valid row, but only one row and I need all of the rows that satisfy this condition.

I am just trying to select all rows where a certain column in that row does not have a specific value. I've tried so many different ways but I keep getting the same results and I am getting really frusterated.

Here is the query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT topic_id 
          FROM ' . TOPIC_TABLE . ' 
          WHERE topic_id!=
         (
          SELECT topic_id 
          FROM ' . TOPIC_TABLE . ' 
          WHERE topic=\'Client Additions\'
         )';
```

Here are some other variations I have tried:

```
$sql = 'SELECT topic_id AS ' . TOPIC_TABLE . '.topic
          FROM ' . TOPIC_TABLE . ' 
          WHERE ' . TOPIC_TABLE . '.topic!=\'Client Additions\'';

$sql = 'SELECT * 
          FROM ' . TOPIC_TABLE . ' 
          WHERE NOT topic LIKE \'Client Additions\'';
```

Here is the output everytime:

```
Array
(
    [Course Catalog] => 3
)
```

and I need the output to be

```
Array
(
    [Course Catalog] => 3
    [Class Schedule] => 4
    [One Time Requests] => 5
    ...
)
```

here are some rows for the table:

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
SELECT 
    topic_id 
FROM 
    TOPIC_TABLE
WHERE 
    topic != 'Client Additions'
```

Comment: Array
(
    [topic_id] => 4
)

Comment: sure one sec lemme generate some

Comment: Yeah, that query should return all the rows in TOPIC_TABLE where the `topic` field is not "Client Additions".  May or may not be case sensitive, depending on your encoding on the topic field.

Comment: here is a pdf dump of the table, sorry I couldn't find a better format. http://sdrv.ms/12BOUik

Comment: @JakeB just copy-paste some rows in the question description

Comment: @JakeB are you sure that's the result of the query ? Array ( [topic_id] => 4 ) ... maybe you have `LIMIT` ?

Comment: i saw... try running this : `SELECT 
    topic_id 
FROM 
    TOPIC_TABLE
WHERE 
    topic_id != 7`

Comment: I think You were right all along and I was just using mysql_fetch_assoc() the wrong way. I think this just returns one row. One minute.

Comment: you should have something like `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {`

Comment: yea i just added that. the function was returning just mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql)) instead of mysql_query($sql).

Comment: Thanks for your help though. I really appreciate it.